# Apache returns page without style only text and images

Tags: php, html, css, apache

I'm dealing with some strange behavior that I don't understand.

So if I type:

```
http://localhost/site/index.php
```

The http server will return a page with no problems at all, a slash after the index.php will  generate a page without any style!

```
http://localhost/site/index.php/
```

How can i solve this?

The beneath CSS link isn't working why?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/fonts.css" />
```

This will work for the slash but if I add something after the slash then I get the all website without styles.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/site/index.php/css/fonts.css" />
```

EDIT:

All of the requested url are OK after adding the complete path on the href's with this function:

```
function baseUrl(){
    return ("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
}
```

Anyway, I've added some rules to the .acccess so now I can't type slash after the index.php but if I type something after the slash everything falls apart :(

Comment: Post your rewrite rules, and contents of .htaccess.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the requested URLs with Firebug or Chrome Developers Tools? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your `<link />` tags `href` attributes and `<img />` tags `src` attributes are prepended with `/`:

Bad:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<img src="img/image.png" />
```

Good:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
<img src="/img/image.png" />
```

This way you are certain that browser will compute correct path.

Comment: all of my link tags are prepended with /, I guess that It might be related with absolute path

Comment: Meanwhile, it's not the complete solution if using a localhost Apache installation, the correct and wise setup demands a virtual host for each project and block the domain on the host file as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing wrong with Apache. Your document is using relative URLs.

For example, you specify `href="myimage.png"` instead of `/myimage.png`

Changing the base URL breaks these relative URLs.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a problem with absolute and relative paths in your css `<link />`. Make sure to use an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to how you define your references to the CSS, images, etc.  If they are defined as relative paths, you are probably in essence looking for them in a wrong directory.

You probably have Apache set to ignore the trailing slash (and just serve index.php rather than look for an index file in index.php directory). The client browser however does not know this and is thinking it is referencing something in a directory called index.php and looking for these files relative to that directory.

To correct this, you should either configure Apache not to ignore the trailing slash (and give a proper 404 error), or implement a rewrite rule to clean up the trailing slash.

Comment: Hey mike I have configured .access to RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / but not solved do you have any ideas on how to solve this one?